# If an ask is closed, are you allowed to ask new one entailing the same question?

Tags: discussion

My first ask, instead of simply being a question, was a detailed rant (my mistake) about the subject. The question ended up closed because of this, with one answer before its closing.

[Why do some people believe Cartman genuinely cares for Kyle?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/87702/64662)

If I don't find the question accurate, am I allowed to ask the same question once more in another ask? Or should I wait for my edit to be approved/reopened as a question?

Answer (score 8):

Okay, I'll be honest with you, this question has quite a bit of an odd history to it.

In its original form that question was somewhat of a rant and pretty much closed for that. It somehow tried to argue against self-made claims that seemed to come out of nowhere. It felt like it was just using a question as a **platform to argue with a position made in another answer or some arbitrary random external website/discussion**.

But then again, removing *all of this* from the question might not have improved it all too much either. Now it severely **lacks context** and we still don't really know what you're really arguing against there and *why* you think that other people think Cartman cares for Kyle, *you* certainly don't seem to think so. You still seem to be arguing against a position noone actually made.

Add to this that there also seem to be a few dubious external factors involved here, since as you can see that question wasn't even asked by you.

- There were **duplicate user accounts** involved in this whole thing, some of which **repeatedly tried to reask this question**, which have been closed as duplicates of the original one.
- Some of those duplicate user accounts have **asked parts of the question in a changed form, which have in turn been answered by yet other duplicate accounts** of the same user (though, those actually have fit better to the site's structure and have not been closed).

Frankly, it all *seems* like you're on some hell-bent quest to rectify statements *someone* made about Cartman's relationship to Kyle *somewhere else*, and going about this in a not all too constructive way. If that is a mischaracterization, I'm sorry, but the above factors really make it difficult to see the forest for the trees here.

Now let's see if we can find a way out of this situation, provided you're not willing to just **leave it be and be satisfied with the *already existing* material** on this site that discusses Cartman's attitude and actions in the situations you seem to be referencing.

*If* this question is really going to be reopened, then there definitely **needs to be more context** to it. You have to elaborate *why* you think other people think Cartman cares about Kyle or *who* thinks so. But don't try to argue against single individuals (be them from other websites or this site) and don't try to argue against your own self-made claims what you think other people think. Show us why it's a commonly accepted interpretation of Cartman's attitude towards Kyle. But also **don't try to *already* answer your own question** by making the arguments already made in another answer. I know that might be difficult, but if you can't do that, maybe you're going about this in the wrong way. **Don't try to use questions as comments to argue with other answers**, that's likely not going to end in a constructive and fruitful question.

*If* you really want to answer your own question, you actually *can* do so. There is no problem with posting an answer to your own question. In fact there is even the option of providing the answer at the same time as the question in one go for exactly that. But please note a few things when doing so:

- Again, try not to argue against invisible claims noone actually made or made in answers to other questions unless you are really asking a substantially different question rather than reiterating another question just to make a point. You **question should make sense as a genuine and significant standalone question** and should make sense even without the answer.
- **Don't give the answer in the question itself**, which makes it a blog post at best and a rant at worst.
- **Don't create duplicate accounts just to answer your own question**, as that is iffy at best, and at worst leads to situations of vote fraud, be they intentional or not, and resulting suspensions and account deletions.

You might also want to **merge some of your existing duplicate accounts** to avoid the danger of commiting vote fraud, the [help center](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) gives some advice on how to do that. But *if* you really want to persue that question further, please **think really thoroughly about it**, what you want to ask, how you can ask that in a constructive way, and how to best do that in line with the workings and rules of this site. *Then* try to either edit your existing question into shape or ask an *entirely different* question if you decide to pursue that line in a *different* way.

Comment: Alright, I've taken what you've said into consideration and made another edit to the question. Please let me know if it doesn't fit the requirements needed